# Python program runs differently after auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python, operating-system, auto-py-to-exe

I wrote a program to iterate over the files of a folder and add the ".jpg" file extension to all files without any file extension. I tested the program on my computer and it works so far.
I compiled the .py file to an .exe file using the auto-py-to-exe package to send the program to a friend who doesn't have python installed on her computer.
When I tested the .exe file I found out that the program behaves differently and doesn't work anymore.
The following code is what I wrote, if you uncomment the print command you can see different files when running the .py and .exe file

```
import os

files = os.listdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
for file in files:
    # print(file)
    split_tup = os.path.splitext(file)
    if split_tup[1] == '':
        os.rename(file, file + '.jpg')
# The input is just that the console doesn't shut down
a = input()
```

For auto-py-to-exe I used following command:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console  "C:/mypath/jpg_wizard.py"
```

Is there a way I can change the auto-py-to-exe command/settings or an alternative code I can use to be able to run the program as an .exe file and get the same result as the .py file?

Comment: maybe you should chdir into `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`? Looks like a relative path problem.

Comment: I added `print(os.getcwd())` to see the working directory. It matches with the path I'm working in so this can't be the problem I suppose

Comment: Could you provide details about 'the program behaves differently and doesn't work anymore.'?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution that works:

```
import os

path = os.getcwd()
folder = os.scandir(path)
for file in folder:
    file = file.name
    split = os.path.splitext(file)
    if split[1] == '':
        os.rename(file, file + '.jpg')
        print(file + '.jpg')
```

Now I use the current working directory as path and iterate over the files I find with `os.scandir(path)`.